# Stop google chart from adding dates in between values

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw `ComboChart`. My problem is that chart keep adding dates in between values, which makes chart unnecessary big:

[image]

My code:

```
var chart;
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
function drawVisualization() {
var graphData = [{"date":new Date(1470903103000),"count1":47,"count2":3},
                {"date":new Date(1472134276000),"count1":92,"count2":20},
                {"date":new Date(1472198154000),"count1":92,"count2":15}];

rowCount = graphData !== undefined ? graphData.length : 0;
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Count1');
data.addColumn("number", "Count2");

for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) { 
    var gDate = graphData[i].date;
    var gCount1 = graphData[i].count1;
    var gCount2 = graphData[i].count2;
    data.addRow([ gDate, gCount1, gCount2]);
}
var options = {
    title : 'Overview',
    vAxis: {title: 'Count'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: { 1: { type: 'line' } },
    //chartArea: { left: 0, top: 0, width: "80%", height: "80%" },
    height: 200,
    width: 500
};

chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

or [go to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st0xzycp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is pretty simple, I simply had to send `string` instead of `dateTime`:

`data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');` => `data.addColumn('string', 'Date');` and `var gDate = graphData[i].date;` => `var gDate = graphData[i].date.toString();`